# how to remove spaces in a list that has a specific character

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, strip

how do you get a list to fix the spaces in the list m.

```
m = ['m, a \n', 'l, n \n', 'c, l\n']
for i in m:
    if (' ') in i:
        i.strip(' ')
```

I got:

```
'm, a \n'
'l, n \n'
'c, l\n'
```

and I want it to return:

```
['m, a\n', 'l, n\n', 'c, l\n']
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the method yet?

Comment: `str.strip()` returns a **new string object**, because strings are immutable. Store it back in your list.

Comment: A list comprehension to replace the list entirely: `m = [i.strip(' ') for i in m]`

Comment: None of your strings have strippable spaces in them (the space is neither at the beginning nor the end of the string) and furthermore, you are throwing away the result of the operation.

Answer (score 2):

The strip() method will strip all the characters **from the end of the string**. In your case, strip starts at the end of your string, encounters a '\n' character, and exits.

It seems a little unclear what you are trying to do, but I will assume that you are looking to clear out any white space between the last non-whitespace character of your string and the newline. Correct me if I'm wrong.

There are many ways to do this, and this may not be the best, but here is what I came up with:

```
m = ['This, is a string. \n', 'another string!    \n', 'final example\n    ']

m = map(lambda(x): x.rstrip() + '\n' if x[-1] == '\n' else x.rstrip(' '), m)

print(m)

['This, is a string.\n', 'another string!\n', 'final example\n']
```

Here I use the built in `map` function iterate over each list element and remove all white space from the end (rstrip() instead of strip() which does both the start and end) of the string, and add in a new line if there was one present in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Your code wouldn't be useful in a script; you are just seeing the REPL displaying the result of the expression `i.strip(' ')`. In a script, that value would just be ignored.

To create a list, use a list comprehension:

```
result = [i.strip(' ') for i in m if ' ' in i]
```

Note, however, `strip` only removes the requested character from either end; in your data, the space *precedes* the newline. You'll need to do something like removing the newline as well, then put it back:

```
    result = ["%s\n" % i.strip() for i in m if ' ' in i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re
m = ['m, a \n', 'l, n \n', 'c, l\n']
final_m = [re.sub('(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=\n)', '', i) for i in m]
```

Output:

```
['m, a\n', 'l, n\n', 'c, l\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

> m = [x.replace(' \n', '\n') for x in m]

If you know that only one space goes before the '\n'